# Return querysets

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

here is the code :

```
def some_brand_mobiles(*brand_names):
    if not brand_names:
        return (Mobile.objects.all())
    else:
        for brand in brand_names:
            return Mobile.objects.filter(brand__name=brand)
```

the expected output for `some_brand_mobiles('Apple', 'Huawei', 'Samsung')` :

```
<QuerySet [<Mobile: Apple iphone 8>, <Mobile: Apple iphone 10>, <Mobile: Apple iphone XIII>]>
<QuerySet [<Mobile: Huawei P40>, <Mobile: Huawei P10 Pro>, <Mobile: Huawei P90 Pro>]>
<QuerySet [<Mobile: Samsung A80>, <Mobile: Samsung A70>]>
```

instead, it returns this only:

```
<QuerySet [<Mobile: Apple iphone 8>, <Mobile: Apple iphone 10>, <Mobile: Apple iphone XIII>]>
```

I know using a return inside of a loop will break the loop and exit the function even if the iteration is not over and I have two options either yielding or appending data to a list and then return the list but none of them work for me and I do not know how to do that and any help would be appreciated

Comment: A `return` returns the value, and thus stops the execution. How would it return multiple items from a function call? You can collect all the elements and return a list for example.

Comment: I know that and I mentioned it but there has to be a way to do that

Comment: well you need some loop mechanism at the caller side to enumerate over the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `return` returns the value, and thus *stops* the function call. It thus can not return multiple items, or at least not with the return statement.

You can collect all the elements and return a list for example:

```
def some_brand_mobiles(*brand_names):
    if not brand_names:
        return Mobile.objects.all()
    else:
        return [
            Mobile.objects.filter(brand__name=brand)
            for brand in brand_names
        ]
```

then the caller can iterate over the items, so:

```
for qs in some_brand_mobiles('Apple', 'Huawei', 'Samsung'):
    print(qs)
```

then the output is thus a list that contains a `QuerySet` per `brand` in the `brand_names`.

Beware that we here make *n* `QuerySet`s with *n* the number of `brand_names`. If you later for example print the list, you make *n* queries, which is not very efficient.

If you simply need all the `Mobile`s for a given list of `brand_names`, you can work with:

```
def some_brand_mobiles(*brand_names):
    if not brand_names:
        return Mobile.objects.all()
    else:
        return Mobile.objects.filter(brand__name__in=brand_names)
```

this makes *one* query, and will return all the relevant `Mobile`s in that query.